# How to add Word Wrap in eclipse mars (4.5.0)

Tags: eclipse, ide

I'm tired of seeing horizontal scrolling in Eclipse and I wanna get rid of it.

How can I get rid of it? In fact, I don't wanna use any plugins.
I was trying to resolve this problem by searching for a special setting in Eclispe, but unfortunately, I haven't searched for a way to do it.

Comment: Word wrap what? Eclipse has dozens of editors and views and you haven't given us anything to go on.

Comment: It's difficult for me to write in english. My native language isn't English.

Answer (score 2):

try this update site. http://dev.cdhq.de/eclipse/updatesite/kepler/
But, have a line number bug in mars...